# Wpf application crash dwrite.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, directwrite

My WPF application crashes on some different PC's.

Here is Windows Event Log:

`Faulting module name: dwrite.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18696,time stamp:0x5915df3a<br/>
Exception code:0xc00000fd<br/>
Fault offset:0x0000706a<br/>
Faulting process id:0x59f8<br/>
Faulting application start time:0x01d3b7aa9dba2f15<br/>
Faulting application path:C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwrite.dll<br/>
Faulting package full name: <br/>
Faulting package-relative application ID:<br/>`

Windows 10 and video driver are updated. dxdiag did not find any problems. Please tell me the direction to solve this problem.

Comment: Is there any managed exception thrown in your WPF application?

Comment: @Kzrystof All exceptions (including UnhandledException and DispatcherUnhandledException) are logged. In this period of time, the logs are empty.

Comment: Is the logging crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Exception code 0xc00000fd is a stack overflow exception. The most likely causes of a stack overflow are infinite recursion (probably an event that keeps on calling itself, but I am not sure if your dll can prevent this by itself) or a huge value type passed as an argument to a function.

Difficult to say anything more concrete given the total absence of any code in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide the code because I don't know what exactly causes this exception. The application itself has more than 300k lines

Comment: Tell me about it! These kinds of problems are not resolved so easily here on SO. What also makes me think, this might be hard problem, is that it appears so deep inside DirectX. If it was something obvious, I guess WPF would crash already next to the caller.